# Is there a proper term and/or symbol for an "agnostic" conclusion?

Tags: logic, notation, terminology, philosophy, nonclassical-logic

My question stems from the material conditional:

$p \rightarrow q\\p\\\therefore\space q$

However, if $\bar p$ then the conditional is silent. I would like a way to represent this fact using, if possible, accepted symbols and terminology.

While I don't like neologisms, I have informally been referring to this as an "agnostic" conclusion (I know, oxymoron) and using $\bar\therefore$ so that in the above syllogism we would have:

$p \rightarrow q\\ \bar p\\ \bar\therefore\space q$

Comment: How about `\nvdash`, $\nvdash$?

Comment: @dfeuer: Ok..so I looked this up, this notation would suggest $\nvdash p$, which means that we are saying we cannot prove p, correct? Typically this is a binary operator, but using it in a unitary way seems to convey the correct meaning. I also came across $\nvDash$, which means "does not semantically entail"...what do you think of that?

Comment: I think I don't know enough about logic to know what $\not\models$ means, but I'm fairly confident that $\vdash$ and $\therefore$ are essentially synonyms.

Comment: I am inclined to agree. Semantic entailment requries, well, semantics. All we are working with is a formalism, so I think the "weaker" $\nvdash q$ suffices as a unitary "shorthand" for $\neg p \nvdash q$.

Comment: Also, I realize i've been using p (premise) not q (conclusion) in my notation. I have meant q (which is probably obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find many such symbols and conceptual variants of this sort of thing in Priest's *An Introduction to Non-Classical Logic: From If to Is*.

Comment: You may or may not be able to find this book online.

Comment: Actually, I found a full color pdf ot the entire thing. It is excellent..I might purchase a copy as well. http://emilkirkegaard.dk/en/wp-content/uploads/An-Introduction-to-Non-Classical-Logic-From-If-to-Is.pdf Thanks!

Comment: OK..from the basic on classical logic, it looks like $\nvdash p$ is closest

Comment: You're welcome. That reads "there is no proof of $p$" to me and is not suggestive agnosticism. Have a look Many-Valued logics, particularly the ones with $i$ representing "indeterminate" between true & false. Also pertinent is Fuzzy Logic. Then it's a matter of assigning a number to the statement, indicating, perhaps, the strength of the agnosticism.

Comment: @Shaun, $a\nvdash b$ means "Given $a$, we cannot prove $b$." Modus ponens can be written $a,a\implies b\vdash b$. However, $\neg a,a\implies b\nvdash b$.

Comment: @Shaun: Well, its not that there is uncertianty. I am referring to the conclusion drawn from the negation of the anacedent in a material conditional. It is a certain conclusion, but what it is saying is that "we cannot conclude that p" but not  "we conclude not p". Perhaps semantic entailment is a better fit $\nvDash p$? I am torn between these two options - my concern is that entailment is too strong, and just need to say it doesn't allow proof ie., $\nvdash p$

Comment: @dfeuer Well, given two sets of formulae, $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$, the notation $\Gamma\vdash\Delta$ is understood to mean, "from $\Gamma$, we can prove $\Delta$"; however, if $\Gamma$ is empty, we simply write $\vdash\Delta$ and say "we can prove $\Delta$".

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: It's not assumed to have connotations of uncertainty; we have probability for that. What it means is that the truth value *itself* is between true & false. It is a stronger statement than simply saying it is unlikely.

Comment: @Shaun: I see what you mean. I recognize the distinction between probability and fuzzy logic. We could say that the truth value of $v(q) = i$, but I was looking for a unitary operator that designates a particualr statment as indeterminate

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really involve symbols, but the first thing that comes to mind is "[vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)". If $p\Rightarrow q$ but $\neg p$ ($\overline p$ if you prefer), then we say that the implication is "vacuously true". I feel like "vacuousness" in this context corresponds to your "the conditional is silent".

In such a situation, without more information, we "can't say anything" about the truth of $q$ (see [a google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22can%27t%20say%20anything%20about%22%20mathematics) showing that this is a decently common phrase).